# How to parse json list into a string - Tweak the code so that I can display a single Json, just as I can display a List of Json

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

I am getting this error:

```
A value of type 'UserModel' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<UserModel>'.
```

I am using `Postman` to generate my api service code (http request that get api from internet). And I am using `https://app.quicktype.io/` to generate my User Model class.

I saw a flutter tutorial which  parsed json into a List because the json was actually a List itself. But In this case, Json is a single item (see pictures for difference). How do i Parse it? and display in a ListView.builder widget?

You can re create this problem using this api link: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1
My code snippet to parse json into a  List is:

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String tempStoreDataFromApi = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        List<DataModel> dataList_1  =    dataModelFromJson(tempStoreDataFromApi);
```

Samples for how a List of json looks, vs how a single item of json looks.
[image: A single Json]
[image: List of Json]
[image: error code]

Comment: could you add your code instead of screenshot? sho we can test the code?

Comment: but then i would have to add 2, 3 .dart files, not just some code snippets. how could have I added files in stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api response is a `Map`. You should use `["data"]` on it if you want to access the list inside it, like this:

```
 List<UserModel> userModelFromJson(String str)-> List<UserModel>.from(((json.decode(str)["data"]) as List).map((x)-> UserModel.fromJson(x)));
```